# How turn text links into HTML links at the client side with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, database

In my db I have saved every links in the form:

```
www.example.com or http://www.example.com
```

Is there a way to turn this text links into HTML links at the client side ( e.g. javascript ) with tag and parameter like this ?:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow">www.example.com</a>
```

Comment: Since you use a db you are talking about a dynamic webapp. Why not generate the links on the server side?

Comment: There are several solutions but more information is needed. I suggest doing it server-side a cherouvim said -- otherwise, yes, its possible with Javascript, but we need some context. Where will this text be? Will there be other anchor tags in the same area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would probably be smarter to do on the server side like cherouvim suggested, but here's a (naive) javascript function that does this for the specified formats (url with and without http://-prefix)

```
    function makeLink(link) { 
        var url, desc;

        if (link.match('^http://')) {
            url = link;
            desc = link.substr(7, link.length - 7);
        } else {
            url = 'http://' + link;
            desc = link;
        }

        return '<a href="' + url + '" rel="nofollow">' + desc + '</a>';
    }
```

Please note it doesn't handle unexpected input (https...) very well, so please don't use as-is in production environment :)

Comment: Do you really think `rel=nofollow` is of any use, since this is generated on the client?

Comment: @nikc - I was just fulfilling the OP's request. Point taken though.

Comment: Oops! Didn't see that up there. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this:

```
text.replace(/([A-Za-z]+:\/\/)?[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(url) {
return url.link(url);
})
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote. This is like answering 42 to the question "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything." It may well be true, but doesn't really explain anything.